# How can I find when the vector values become zero?

Tags: database, date, if-statement, vector, vectorization

I have a series of dates along with a numeric vector, for example:

```
dates <- c("01-01-1990", "01-02-1990", "01-03-1990", "01-04-1990", "01-05-1990", "01-06-1990", "01-07-1990", "01-08-1990", "01-09-1990", "01-10-1990")
values <- c(23423,54645,12342,0,3453,234123,0,0,0,0)
df <- data.frame(dates, values)
```

And I would like to obtain the index/date when it becomes cero until the end, in this case, it should indicate "01-07-1990" or 7. Is there an elegant way to do this? I can't think of anything that makes the distinction between the first zero and the last ones.

Comment: What database/RDMBS implementation is this in?